# Metacity/GNOME full screen as default

Tags: gnome, fullscreen, kiosk, metacity

I recently discovered the keyboard shortcut for metacity's "full screen" option, where a window is fully maximised with titlebar and border hidden.  I like this mode a lot, and for one of my systems would like to make it the default for all new windows.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm am now using Ubuntu's "maximus" utility to do this for me.

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://www.enigmacurry.com/category/gnome/), which indicates how to do it interactively. My thought is that you may be able to write a script using wmctrl to monitor newly opened windows and set fullscreen on them. Then, just add this script to your GNOME startup.